# React code renders on localhost fine but is not working when i open it up manually in google chrome(by opening index.html directly without using npm)

Tags: reactjs

My react app was working fine with live server started from `npm start` after installing with `create-react-app`. But later when trying to open same index.html directly from chrome(double clicking on index.html) , only the content of index.html is visible in the browser. Nothing of App.js pointed to root was rendered.

I'm total beginner to React.

This is my App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>This is a test</h1>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And this is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <h1>This is second test</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Edit: Only "This is second test" Loads on the file opened on browser whereas "This is a test" "This is second test" loads on the live-server.

Comment: It looks to me like you are probably using a webpack configuration to build your react and put everything together, and that isn't happening when you double click the files. So what you should do is to build to a static output you can open by clicking in the filesystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to read into `npm run build` to create files you can serve statically